# Is it possible to set a width to a vim document so newlines are inserted automatically?

Tags: vim

I want some text I am typing in vim to automatically break into a new line after so many characters have been typed, rather than letting me type out lines of infinite length.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`textwidth`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27textwidth%27) option does that.

```
:set tw=78
```

As the help points out, you may want to check the option called
[`formatoptions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27) or [`fo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27) for short. This will provide you more control
over formatting aspects. The [table of options](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table) is also helpful (help under
`fo-table` tag).